# Wait in bash script for env to load in tmux session

Tags: shell, sh, tmux

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Startup tmux session, activate env inside session, wait, execute invoke command

DIR=$(echo $DIR_HOME)
CLOUD=$'cloud_sql'

tmux new -s $CLOUD -d
printf "Starting: $CLOUD \n"
tmux send-keys "cd $DIR_HOME" C-m
tmux send-keys 'pipenv shell' C-m
printf 'Env Started! \n'
if [[ "-z ${ENV_ACTIVE}" ]]; then
  tmux send-keys -t $CLOUD "wait 15" C-m
  tmux send-keys -t $CLOUD 'inv gce.cloud-sql-proxy -p 5432' C-m
else
  tmux send-keys 'Server not ready!'
fi
printf "$CLOUD started.  Attach using: \n\n"
printf "tmux attach -t $CLOUD \n\n"

exit 0
```

I'd like for the `pipenv shell` command to  finish before (inside the tmux session) running `inv gce.cloud-sql-proxy ..` but for some reason I see it executes those commands before/during the activation of `pipenv shell`..

On a side note, if I added a `tmux attach -t $CLOUD` before the if statement, it seemed to work although this was ideal and id like to exit the tmux session upon completion.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, for me it was:

```
tmux send-keys "pipenv shell" C-m
tmux send-keys "python run.py" C-m
```

I solved it by appending the following to my Pipfile:

```
[scripts]
serve = "python run.py"
```

Then I changed my tmux to:

```
tmux send-keys "pipenv run serve" C-m
```

This runs my script called serve, i.e., runs a program using the env without needing to load it first. You can probably do the same by creating a script in Pipfile for inv gce.cloud-sql.proxy... and run that.

Comment: hmm, thats interesting.  I'm going to try something like that as well; thanks or the tip!  I ended up using a crude while [wait 7 seconds] do nothing .. type of loop.  Others have just went w/ docker for this sort of use case but that has its own headaches as well...